# Java wait for variable to change

Tags: java, javafx

I am sitting with a little problem here, and i has been searching for hours for any soultion now, but cant seem to find any, and i hope you can help me.

I have these methods:

```java
public String getInput(){
    //Wait here somehow
    return "Whatever to return";
}

public void keyTrigger(KeyEvent event){
    if(event.getCode().equals(KeyCode.ENTER)){
        String[] getInput = gameLog.getText().split("\n");
            input = getInput[getInput.length - 1]; //Input is a variable in the class
            //Tell the getInput() to continue from where i waited
    }
}
```

So if anyone can tell me how the make the first method wait for a response from the other method, i woul be very happy, because none i have tried so far has worked

EDIT...
Sorry guys, i have missed out on some details.

1st: I am developing a GUI in JavaFX, and the gameLog variable is a textarea, and thats why im splitting the String on linebreaks.

2nd: when i call getInput() i want it to wait for the user to press enter, then get the input variable

Comment: You could use a basic `Object.wait` vs `Object.notify[All]` synchronization idiom, although I suspect your issue is rather more complicated and can't be answered as such.

Comment: You can try with `Observer` and `Observable`: http://www.javaworld.com/article/2077258/learn-java/observer-and-observable.html

Comment: Why do you need a blocking call, in JavaFX the UI is event driven. So why not starting some useful action in the event handler of the TextArea?

Comment: If you need to block on a String input from the event handler, you might use a LinkedBlockingQueue<String> and call take() in your getInput() and use offer(input) in the event hadler...

Answer (score 1):

Your immediate request would be satisfied by a `CompletableFuture`:

```
public String getInput(){
  final CompletableFuture<String> fut = new CompletableFuture<>();
  commonFuture = fut;
  return fut.join();
}
```

In the above, you need to provide a variable `commonFuture` which is accessible both from the above code and from your `KeyEvent` listener, and will serve as the point of contact between these two pieces of code. In the listener you would say

```
commonFuture.complete(getInput[getInput.length - 1]);
```

and at that point the `join` call in `getInput()` would complete, returning this value.

However, I urge you to seriously think through your current design, which demands such synchronous blocking. You may be able to rework so that `getInput` is replaced by a callback method which gets invoked when the input value is available.

Answer (score 0):

I don't really understand your issue here, from common logic I guess your `getInput()` should read from command line and return the value as `String`. You don't need to write any special code for it, for reading from command line you should use `BufferedReader`, see the example below.

```
public String getInput(){
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
String line;
try{
    line = reader.readLine();
    }catch(IOException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
        }
return line;
}
```

Also this part of your code, `input = getInput[getInput.length - 1];` I don't see a point of `getInput.length - 1` because `getInput()` will return a whole string so you don't need to trim it unless you explicitly want to do it. So you can just write `input = getInput();`, with assumption that variable `input` is of type `String`.

Comment: OP is developing a GUI (`KeyEvent` is a clue).

Comment: Yes and that clue also points that "getInput()" is reading from a keyboard, maybe not from a command line but from another text-input window. If he's using a library such as swing then there are functions already in place for such input handling.

Comment: Which "such input handling" do you have in mind? I don't follow you at all.

Comment: If he's programming GUI he must be using a library for all the things unless he wants to create his own from very scratch. In Swing you got numerous input modes and such inputs are already synced in a way that they "wait" until you enter a command/text and click enter/button which activates the execute function. It's already built in so I don't see a use for OPs question, unless he's just asking how to sync 2 processes then he's on a whole different path atm.

Comment: You must be referring to modal dialogs. But here OP wants to block while receiving input on a single text field.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of trying to block until the variable changes, you should use a [`StringProperty`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/beans/property/StringProperty.html) and register listeners with it.

Here's some skeleton code:

```
private final StringProperty input = new SimpleStringProperty();

public StringProperty inputProperty() {
    return input ;
}

public final String getInput() {
    return inputProperty().get();
}

public final void setInput(String input) {
    inputProperty().set(input);
}

// event handler (I'm assuming):
public void keyTrigger(KeyEvent event){
    if(event.getCode().equals(KeyCode.ENTER)){
        String[] getInput = gameLog.getText().split("\n");
            inputProperty().set(getInput[getInput.length - 1]); 
    }
}
```

Now you can have code execute when the `input` is changed:

```
inputProperty().addListener((obs, oldInput, newInput) -> {
    // newInput contains the new value set to the input property....
});
```

The [Properties and Bindings tutorial](http://www.oracle.com/pls/topic/lookup?ctx=javase80&id=JFXBD107) has more details on using JavaFX properties.